# how to save FBProfilePictureView in NSUserDefaults\Core Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook graph to load a user's image to an iOS app.
The image is then placed inside a UIView in order to present it.

I would like to present that same picture if internet connection is not available, and if internet is available to fetch the image from Facebook.

How do I save the image:

- to NSUserDefaults?
- to Core Data?
- to App folder?

and how do I retrieve it later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about image caching - keep in mind that you can't just infinitely store images as they are downloaded (there is a chance that your application will take up way too much disk space eventually). You need to define some criteria for purging all of this data - either data that is unused or maybe outdated - that's up to you. There are a lot of ways to tackle the caching issue, just Google it and I'm sure you'll find some useful stuff.

As for storing images - what you want to do is get the UIImage's data (by using functions like `UIImageJpegRepresentation` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation`). These functions will return an NSData instance that can either be stored in NSUserDefaults (not the place for image caching) or on a file in your Cache directory (much better and won't give Apple a good reason to reject your app for bad storage practices).

Also, don't accidentally try to call these functions on an FBProfilePictureView instance - that's just a class Facebook created for displaying profile pictures (it is in fact a UIView that has a UIImageView subview of a profile image. Within this UIImageView you can get the UIImage itself). [How can I convert FBProfilePictureView to an UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889725/how-can-i-convert-fbprofilepictureview-to-an-uiimage)

Good luck

Comment: The link you provided it the end is the one I was talking about..
They say it returns "nil" there, and the other one dosent have any "OK" on it.. is it good?

Comment: I think it isn't a robust solution anyway - I'd think of a way to obtain UIImages another way - maybe query facebook via FQL? I wouldn't try to traverse subviews and check if they have a UIImageView, very not-elegant.

Comment: I don't know how to use the FQL.
Can I just extract the fbprofilepictureview's sub view? (the image) and save it to the app folder? if so, how..

Comment: Again, you should be able to do so (not sure how) but it wouldn't be the best way

Comment: For querying friends with FQL, see step 2 in this guide: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/run-fql-queries-ios-sdk/#step2

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to cache With NSUserDefaults

//save

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myImage];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:data forKey:@"yourKeyImage"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

//get

```
NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"yourKeyImage"];
NSData *received = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:received];
```