# Create iOS image button with URL source in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

First off, I'm completely new to Objective-C. 
In my app I want to create a list of buttons with the background image set to the profile picture of my friends on facebook. To this end I was intending to use the url to the profile picture as the background image of the button. Is this even possible or would I have to download the image content first, saving it locally on the device and then use it?

What would be the most straightforward way of accomplishing this?

Thanks in advance!

T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `FBProfilePictureView` from the Facebook iOS SDK to display the profile picture. Documentation available [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBProfilePictureView). I'm sure if you search for `FBProfilePictureView` you can also find sample code.

Answer (score 3):

As Joel [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19350127/2342917), you can use `FBProfilePictureView` to get the image. If you don't want to use the Facebook API, you can use this really (too) simple method, just to understand the mechanism :

```
// Creation of an UIImageView (which will be used as the button's background)
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

// Fetch the image data from a specific URL
NSString *imageURL = @"yourProfilePictureURL";
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];

// Assign the image data we fetched to the UIImageView
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

// Creation of the UIButton (if you didn't do this in your story board)
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];

// Set the background image of the button with the image you fetched before
[button setBackgroundImage:imageView.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// Add the button to the view (useless if you used storyboard)
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

As I said, this method is pretty straightforward, understandable and easy to use, but I suggest you to use the Facebook API instead (It will require much more work). See the  [`FBProfilePictureView`documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBProfilePictureView), then [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364495/fbprofilepictureview-object-wont-show-image) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889725/how-can-i-convert-fbprofilepictureview-to-an-uiimage) for  already asked questions about this class.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that `dataWithContentsOfURL` is synchronous and will block the main thread (no es bueno), so you'd need to run it on a background thread. Which is probably beyond the capabilities of the OP.

Comment: If you want to avoid the Facebook SDK and just load it from a URL I'd probably use UIImageView+AFNetworking category extension so you don't have to worry about writing the async image loading from scratch.

Comment: Yep, I fully understand that, I gave this solution as a simple and straightforward one.

Using UIImageView+AFNetworking category is a great idea, I agree!

Comment: Guys, thank you both very much for your answers. I was torn between who to award the "answer" to seeing as Joel first responded with the suggestion of FBProfilePictureView which is perhaps the best way to go about what I need to do. But then Arnaud responded with exactly what I asked i.e. literally creating a UIIMage object and setting it  as the background image of a button (and a very comprehensive example code snipper). HOwever I awarded answer to Joel just because that is the solution I will likely implement. Thanks guys.