# How to get the FBProfile picture into UIImageView

Tags: ios, facebook

I have an iOS app that integrated with FBLoging. And I know it can assign the profile picture into a `UIView` like this.

`// This method will be called when the user information has been fetched
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
  self.profilePictureView.profileID = user.id;
}`

But what I wanna do is to get that profile picture into my already available `UIImageView`. In order to do this I have a Singleton class. I want to get that image as a `UIImage` and assign to the variable inside that Singleton class. When another `Viewcontroller` load I want to assign that singleton class's `UIImage` into my `Viewcontroller`'s `UIImageView`

How can I do this. please help me.
Thank you

Comment: if the following answers are not sufficient to you, let me know

Comment: yes can u give me ur solution too,, ncos Im getting the profilepictureview as null according to vishal's answer

Comment: can u fetch the username and id from FB? war about raki's answer?.And which framework u using,FB or Social?

Comment: yes I can fetch username,email,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Facebook user.id with you, you can create the imageURL like this

```
   NSString * url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large",user.objectID];
```

Then save this url to your singleton class. And you can download like this if you need.(You can download each time you required or download once and save in to a file, if required ,fetch from file).

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
UIImage *userImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Comment: here when I put user.id it getting null, but when I type the user object I can see id is coming along with the other data

Comment: send me that response to me

Comment: email = "test@gmail.com"; "first_name" = Fname; gender = male; id = 66666666666666660; "last_name" = Lastname; link = "facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/66666666666666660/";; locale = "en_US"; "middle_name" = Middle; name = "Fname Midddle Lname"; timezone = "5.5"; "updated_time" = "2014-06-19T09:23:23+0000"; verified = 1;

Comment: its enough, you can extract id from here. is it dictionary r8?.send <FBGraphUser>user objects NSLOg.

Comment: that was the user object I got it py typing po user

Comment: po user.id
error: property 'id' not found on object of type 'id'
error: 1 errors parsing expression

Comment: i think that deprecated.tyr po user.objectID                  >objectID
Typed access to the user ID.
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *objectID;
Discussion:
Note this typically refers to the "id" field of the graph object (i.e., equivalent to [self objectForKey:@"id"]) but is differently named to avoid conflicting with Apple's non-public selectors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56746/discussion-between-suhail-and-user2889249).

Comment: I had to use [user objectforkey:@"id"];

Answer (score 1):

You can get the image from the profilePictureImageView using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12479572/622889) .
Once you have the image, then you can save it in your Singleton class as is or you can assign it to your imageView.

The method in the link only works once the image has been downloaded into the profilePictureImageView. So you need to take care of that, maybe by waiting. Or keep checking it for non nil value after some time in succession.

Comment: according to that answer when I give it,, it exit from the for loop by  giving profilepictureView nil y is that?

Comment: Are you sure the image has been downloaded ? Can you try using a wait() for some time and then try it ?

Comment: inside the for loop Im checking the img is null or not but the problem is when first time it reaches to the foor loop it exits,, and I checked by giving self.profilePictureView.profileID = user.id; here the user id getting null, but when I put print the user object in debug area id is comming with other data

Comment: send me the debug data

Comment: email = "test@gmail.com";
    "first_name" = Fname;
    gender = male;
    id = 66666666666666660;
    "last_name" = Lastname;
    link = "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/66666666666666660/";
    locale = "en_US";
    "middle_name" = Middle;
    name = "Fname Midddle Lname";
    timezone = "5.5";
    "updated_time" = "2014-06-19T09:23:23+0000";
    verified = 1;

Comment: debug data was something like this

Comment: Don't do user.id, get user id like this : user["id"], this looks like to be a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

you can try following method

```
[[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *FBuser, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
      // Handle error
    }

    else {
      NSString *userName = [FBuser name];
      NSString *userImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", [FBuser id]];
    }
  }];
```

you have to store this url into your singleton class

Comment: inside which method do I need to do this?

Comment: create -(NSString *)getFacebookPicture{},in your class write that code inside this method,return userImageUrl.then call where you want

Comment: can I put inside - (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user there is a FBGraphuser object alredy available  so  can I just put only NSString *userImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", [FBuser id]]; this line inside my method?

Comment: so you have  FBGraphuser object already you can put inside that method