# Get an image from FBProfilePictureView swift

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

When logging in with fb,  the following UIView displays the users profile picture

```
@IBOutlet var profilePictureView : FBProfilePictureView
```

How would I get the image so that I can use it elsewhere/save it to a server?

Here is the fb documentation on FBProfilePictureView (in Objective-C) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBProfilePictureView
Here is a swift port of the fb login, which works well.
https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/68653/This-is-a-swift-port-of-the-official-Fac
And here is the same code, but in objective C
[How can I convert FBProfilePictureView to an UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889725/how-can-i-convert-fbprofilepictureview-to-an-uiimage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use alternate Idea also,

**Objective-C**

```
 NSString *userImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", [FBuser objectID]];
```

change the types also

- type: small, normal, large, square

**Swift**

```
 let avatar = "https://graph.facebook.com/\(user.objectID)/picture?width=640&height=640"
```

or another choice

```
let url = NSURL.URLWithString("https://graph.facebook.com/\(user.objectID)/picture?width=640&height=640");
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check
yourimagename.image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

Comment: How would I convert this string into a UIImage?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the answer you linked to (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12479572/2274694), you can treat the `FBProfilePictureView` as you would any `UIView` and traverse the subviews in order to find the `UIImageView` and access the image:

```
var image:UIImage!

for obj in profilePictureView.subviews {
    if obj is UIImageView {
        let objImg = obj as UIImageView
        image = objImg.image
        break
    }
}
```